# JQuery : using bind for newly added table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a HTML table with one of the columns being a textbox column.

I have set up a bind on the textbox when ever the textbox value is changed through the UI an attribute is added/updated as follows:

```
$('#container').find('.tableClass tbody').find('input[type=text]').bind('input', function () {
   $(this).attr('data-val', this.value);                
            });
```

This works fine for rows loaded on form load. But when I add new a row to the table it does not seem to work. I tried using something like below to utilize event delegation but this does not work.

```
$('#container').find('.tableClass tbody').on('bind', 'input[type=text] input', function () {
    $(this).attr('data-val', this.value);                
        });
```

Any ideas for how to get this to work for newly added rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `.on()` incorrectly. The first argument should be the event name (just like the first argument to `.bind()`), the second argument should be the selector. You used `bind` where the event belongs, and then you put the event name (`input`) into the selector. It should be:

```
$('#container').find('.tableClass tbody').on('input', 'input[type=text]', function () {
    $(this).attr('data-val', this.value);                
});
```

Comment: Awesome. You rock. Thanks a lot!